# Android layout and scaling ImageView issue

Tags: android, layout, imageview, scaling

I am trying to achieve something that on the face of it I thought would be easy but have researched loads and still struggling.

I am setting an ImageView that will act as a background where parts of the image are areas that buttons should sit on top. For example the background looks a bit like this:

[image: Background]

This is set to fitCenter so that it scales with the correct aspect ratio on all screen types like this:

[image: Background resized]

Now I am trying to place ImageButtons over the white areas like so:

[image: Buttons over white areas]

I am trying this by aligning each Imagebutton to the top left of the background imageView and then setting margins to aset it in the right place. This works for some screen types, but when the background gets resized because the device is smaller than the background image for example I am finding that the buttons on top dont resize with it so I get the effect like the following:

[image]

Here is the type of layout I am trying (with just one button here):

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/outer" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:src="@drawable/no_pills_pane" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/> 
<ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:src="@drawable/pill_pink" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:background="@null" android:layout_marginTop="50dp" android:layout_marginLeft="44dp" android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageView1" android:layout_alignLeft="@id/imageView1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm sure there must be an easier way to go about this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to center ImageButton within ImageView, simply set alignBottom, alignLeft, alignRight, alignTop to ImageView

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not trying to center the imagebutton, I am trying to place multiple imagebuttons over the background at very specific places. I am doing this using by aligning to to left on imageview then using margins to place them. This works for certain screen res's but not for all as the buttons dont seem to scale with the imageview